# Updating and saving a global parameter creates a duplicate. Is this expected behaviour in any circumstances?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

This may be a bug report masquerading as a question, but if I do the following steps -

1. Create a global parameter in Azure Data Factory
2. Save the parameter
3. Open it and update the value
4. Save the parameter

ADF is creating another parameter with the same (see attached screenshot) and complaining about parameters with non-unique names.  If I save it again, or attempt to delete one of the parameters, it just duplicates any parameters.

[image]

Yes, I have tried the obvious items like different browsers and clearing the browser cache.  Before I raise this as a bug (it seems kind of obvious to have slipped through QA) are there any circumstances, such as permissions, where this is legitimate behaviour for the ADF studio?

Comment: I also tried for me it's not creating another new parameter it just updating initial one